# Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms reports not working on mac

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

i am using Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms version 9.0, in my asp.net mvc2 app, with vs 2010,4.0.
The report viewer doesnt open the pdf or excel files on Mac OS with safari or firefox browsers, but works on windows.
is there any fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, the namespaces and dll's which start with Microsoft are targeted for Windows OS's only. Just check from MSDN which Operating Systems are the target for Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.

Comment: thanks for ur reply, but i couldnt find anything mentioned in msdn as such. the whole website works which is written on .net 4.0,just few cross browser compatibility issues. it works on mozilla on mac as well.

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed the issue by changing the code as below , i.e. download as attachment.

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "filename=test.pdf");
```

**to**
    Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=test.pdf");